# Whay can't I nclude a link in a hidden field?

Tags: html, forms

Why can't I include a URL in a hidden input field?
I need to so I can clone a db record from one form into a new record. Is it not possible to have a link in a hidden input field?

I populate the form from a db search and enter the found items into the "value" of hidden fields. This is my form sample:

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
  <input type="hidden" id="custId" name="custId" value="<a target="_blank" href="http://www.rkheadshots.com">RK Headshots</a>">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The only time I have an issue is if there is a link in the tect being placed into a hidden field.

You can see from that sample hidden field that
RK Shots" />
will be visible. Happens to similar areas if there is a link in the value I'm trying to place into a hidden field.

Thoughts?

Comment: Please share some code snippet

Comment: `value='<a target="_blank" href="http://www.rkheadshots.com">RK Headshots</a>"'`

Comment: Joy, I can see my form snippet on this page... not you?

Comment: You're trying to put an anchor link element in a form? Why not just the href?

Comment: j08691, that doesn't work either. tried all kinda variations. w3shchools has a page where you can try various things, all show the same error. Truncated text showing what's being linked and the ">

Comment: Phix, not sure what you mean. I'm trying to clone a db record and sometimes one or two of the fields have a link within them. If there is a link weirdness happens. No links within all is fine, leading me to question wheter a hidden field can contain a href url

Answer (score 0):

The non-escaped double-quotes are a problem.  You could use single quotes (simplest option) like...

```
<input type="hidden" id="custId" name="custId" value='<a target="_blank" href="http://www.rkheadshots.com">RK Headshots</a>'>
```

Or, escape the double-quotes like...

```
<input type="hidden" id="custId" name="custId" value="<a target=&quot;_blank&quot; href=&quot;http://www.rkheadshots.com&quot;>RK Headshots</a>">
```

Comment: Kevin, Single quotes still causes issues, the double quote way seems to work OK, but changing those quotes surrounding a link when all that text including any links is yanked from a db to populate that hidden field is something I need to think about a little.

Comment: If the value is being given with the HTML and the HTML is always the same, could you strip out just the link and put that in the value?  Then when you need it again, you just tack on the HTML around it?

Comment: Solved.I use a scripting language pretty much no ones has heard of lol. Been using it for nearly 20 years. Those who use it love it.... WebDNA. it has tags called [url] and [convertchars] which when I use in the proper order solve my issue. Kevin got me to thinking of what to do about those quotes surrounding the url, which is where all my problems started..